# How to execute command once in an infinite loop

Tags: linux, bash, infinite-loop

There is a idea of code:

```
while true; do
*check variable*
if [ variable == true ]; then
*command1 to execute*
.
.
.
*commandN to execute*
fi
done
```

How to execute *command1* only once without leaving this loop?
Obviously, *command1* should be executed only once every time when *variable* is true?

EDIT: I don't want to leave the loop because it is a part of monitoring script for headless debian home server/storage device. Check variable is a check if VPN connection is on. Or if there is a new file in a folder. Or if there is a new user logged in. Triggers might be countless. Command1 is send email notification about it. Or write a new line to custom logfile. Again, countless applications. I dont want to be mailed every iteration. It is all about neverending checking status and executing command once the status changed.

Comment: Set the variable to false before the next iteration. (The syntax is simpler if you compare against empty vs nonempty value; shell variables are strings.)

Comment: Why do you not want to leave the loop? Why not just bring command1 out and execute it if the variable is true there?

Answer (score 0):

Leave the variable outside of the loop if you only want it to execute once -

Answer (score 0):

There is a closer to real life example:
I would like to continuously monitor audio output. 
In case that audio sink is not set to HDMI I want see neverending on-screen reminders every 10 seconds, but be mailed only once when it happened.

So:

```
while true
do
if ! pacmd -list-sinks | grep -q "active port: <hdmi-output-0>"; then AUDIO_HDMI="false"; fi

if [ "$AUDIO_HDMI" == "false" ]; then
 MSG="Audio sink is not set to HDMI!"
 notify-send $MSG
 echo "$MSG" | mail -s "WARNING" me@somwhere.com # <-PART OF CODE TO BE EXECUTED ONCE
fi

sleep 10
done
```

Any ideas how to send that email only once?

Maybe there is another way to find the solution rather than infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do it with another variable involved.

```
while true
do
if ! pacmd -list-sinks | grep -q "active port: <hdmi-output-0>"; then AUDIO_HDMI="false"; else SEND_MAIL="reset"; fi

if [ "$AUDIO_HDMI" == "false" ]; then
 MSG="Audio sink is not set to HDMI!"
 notify-send $MSG
 if [ "$SEND_MAIL" != "sent" ]; then echo "$MSG" | mail -s "WARNING" me@somwhere.com && SEND_MAIL="sent"; fi
fi

sleep 10
done
```

There is no elegance in this way but at least it works. Might there be another way to achieve the goal?